# Why does the default wallpaper open properly but get immediately get replaced by black screen

Tags: dell, screen, desktop-background

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and the OS is up to date. The machine is a Dell XPS 13.  I have three other laptops all running the same software and they just bring up the FocalFossa background as they should.  The Dell, however, once someone is logged in,begins with the default Purple Fossa image but within a second or two writes over that with a black screen. The dock remains in place and is functional.  Oddly, clicking on the "Activities" button changes the screen to the default wallpaper temporarily.  The background then goes back to black when an activity is selected.

This problem is relatively new and is independant of the user.  Any ideas?

Comment: Depending on the CPU/iGPU generation you may need newer kernels.

Comment: The kernel is 5.14.0-1024-oem #26-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 17 14:35:50 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.  As far as I know it's the newest,

Comment: I guess I shouldn't complain too much since the machine works fine except for this annoying problem.  Any other ideas appreciated.

Comment: The problem persists through all the updates since my original post.  One other thing is that when I call up a display of the workspaces available, they all display properly.

Comment: This problem persists.  Maybe I should offer a reward.

Comment: Here's another hint.  The black screen leaves a narrow border of the purple Fossa screen and mousing over the junction between the black and the purple creates one of the little double-ended arrows as though the black portion can be resized.  It doesn't do so when I move the cursor, however.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.  I have no idea why it works. Apparently there was an app called "desktopfolder" which does nothing these days but cause the problem I asked about.  The solution is:

```
 sudo apt purge desktopfolder
```

Then reboot.